# How do I parse my object that is returned in a component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to parse the object in console `myVar`, it always shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

```
const MESSAGES = defineMessages({
    tempKey: {
       id: "mypages.installment.everyday.monthconfig.4",
       defaultMessage:'{ "minamount":1001, "fixedfee":95, "admincharges":25, "purchaseCode":4 }',
       description: "message"
    }
});
```

inside my render method in react

```
let myVar = JSON.stringify(<Message {...MESSAGES.tempKey} />)
console.log('myVar', myVar)
```

Comment: What does the `defineMessages` method do?

Comment: import {defineMessages, injectIntl} from 'react-intl'; used from react library to form the structure